# How to get the character for an XLib key wrt the keyboard layout?

Tags: c++, linux, internationalization, x11, xlib

Using `XKeycodeToKeysym` (in C++) I can get the KeySym for a key-press event. From what I understand this already should respect the keyboard layout. However, when I switch a keyboard layout (between english and hebrew) I get the same KeySym. I suspect that the Xlib Keysym only honors keyboard layout defined in the X11 level? In my system the keyboard layouts are defined only in the desktop environment level (Mate). And if so, is there any way to get the correct character without using a toolkit like Qt / GTK? Must I handle each desktop environment separately?

**[Edit]**

I've tried the following (according to Andrey's suggestion), which doesn't work:

```
#include <X11/XKBlib.h>

#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
    Window root, window;
    XSetWindowAttributes swa;
    root = DefaultRootWindow( display );
    XSelectInput( display, root, MappingNotify );
    std::memset(&swa, 0, sizeof swa );
    swa.event_mask = MappingNotify | KeyPressMask;
    window = XCreateWindow( display, root, 50, 200, 1024, 768, 0, CopyFromParent, InputOutput, CopyFromParent,
                             CWEventMask, &swa );
    XMapRaised( display, window );
    int xkbEventCode=0, n0=0, n1=0, n2=0, n3=0;
    bool isOk = XkbQueryExtension(  display, &n0, &xkbEventCode, &n1, &n2, &n3 ) ==True;
    assert( isOk );
    isOk = XkbSelectEvents( display, XkbUseCoreKbd, XkbAllEventsMask, XkbAllEventsMask ) ==True;
    assert( isOk );
    while (true) {
        XEvent event;
        std::memset( &event, 0, sizeof event );
        XNextEvent( display, &event );
        if (event.type == xkbEventCode)
            switch (reinterpret_cast<XkbEvent*>(&event)->any.xkb_type) {
              case XkbNewKeyboardNotify:
              case XkbMapNotify: {
                std::cout << "Keyboard mapping has changed." << std::endl;
                break;
                }
            default:  break;
            }
        else
            switch (event.type) {
              case KeyPress: {
                KeyCode keyCode = event.xkey.keycode;
                int keySymsPerkeyCode=0;
                KeySym *keySyms( XGetKeyboardMapping(display, keyCode, 1, &keySymsPerkeyCode)),
                       *keySym = keySyms;
                while (keySymsPerkeyCode--  &&  *keySym != NoSymbol) {
                    std::cout << *keySym << std::endl;
                    ++keySym;
                    }
                XFree( keySyms );
                break;
                }
              case MappingNotify: {
                std::cout << "Keyboard mapping has changed." << std::endl;
                break;
                }
              default:  break;
              }
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250059/x11-mappingnotify-event-only-fires-when-modifying-keyboard-layout-inside-gnome-t

Answer (score 2):

I can answer only at a lower level, don't know what `XKeycodeToKeysym` does.

You need to listen for [MappingNotify](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/window-state-change/mapping.html) event and each time you receive it re-read new mapping (usually this means keyboard layout / language changed ) with [XGetKeyboardMapping](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGetKeyboardMapping.html)

This is part of core X protocol,  desktop environment / WM independent

**update:**

Looks like xlib enables XKeyboard extension by default. After it's enabled you need to explicitly express interest in mapping change events ( unlike with core protocol where MappingNotify is always sent to all clients ) - see http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XkbSelectEvents.3.html

```
 XkbSelectEvents (display, XkbUseCoreKbd, XkbAllEventsMask, XkbAllEventsMask);
```

After that you respond to `XkbMapNotify` event and do [XkbGetMap()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xkbgetmap) to get new layout

Comment: I'm afraid that function gives me the exact same KeySym, which doesn't take into account my keyboard layout in Mate.

Comment: which one? XGetKeyboardMapping returns a new mapping after keyboard layout is changed. Also, do you get MappingNotify event when you change layout with Mate switcher ?

Comment: No, I don't get a `MappingNotify`, and `XGetKeyboardMapping` returns the same mapping.

Comment: could you post simple example of the code you are using?

Comment: also, can you test with non-mate environment? ( gnome/ kde/ unity )

Comment: I've added code. I've tested also with Gnome and KDE - the same.

Comment: Interesting, looks like you don't get MappingNotify if XKEYBOARD extension is used ( and xlib automatically enables it ). I was not using xkeyboard in my (non xlib) code - http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/kbproto/xkbproto.html#Interactions_Between_XKB_and_the_Core_Protocol

Comment: Xkb event type stored in a sub field of event, top level id is the same for all events. See usage examples at https://github.com/search?l=cpp&q=XkbMapNotify&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: You need to compare with `event->any.xkb_type`. Try to print `event.type` in your while loop and you'll see that it actually react on layout change

Comment: hi, your example is incomplete and with typos. This is what I tested: https://gist.github.com/sidorares/6a8cd9499b5b2024e55c

Comment: My example was incomplete and with typos because I've extracted it from my full program, because I prefered to post shorter code here. Anyway I've changed my question to contain the full code which doesn't work for me. Can u plz try the code in my question and tell me whether it works for u?

Comment: your example works for me ( ubuntu 15.10 in virtualbox ) - prints "Keyboard mapping has changed" when I switch layout

Comment: Which desktop environment do you use? Did u define the keyboard mappings in X or in the desktop environemt? I'll install ubuntu 15.10 in vbox and I want to ducplicate exactly what u did, because now this starts to drive me crazy..

Comment: default ubuntu ( unity ) but I just checked and results are the same in IceWM ( or no WM ) if I change layout manually with `setxkbmap -layout ru` `setxkbmap -layout en_US`

Comment: Ok, I've tested in Ubuntu with Unity and indeed works. However, I then tried Ubuntu with Mate / GNOME / KDE, and again it didn't work. My guess is, from the desktop environments I've tested, Unity is the only one that changes the layout in X, and therefore X is aware of the change. Anyway, I'm still stuck with my problem, to which I doubt whether there is a solution at all.

Comment: works for me even inside Xephyr / twm so might be gnome/mate/kde config issue

Comment: Works for me in KDE.

Comment: Andrey: Let's say I'm lucky and I get the mapping events. I still have the following questions: 1. What do the keySym-s mean? Are they in some encoding (I can't identify it). 2. I get several keySyms per keyCode. How do I know which one to choose? 3. What happens if a sequence of keys generates a single character? For example, in chinese it's impossible to map all characters to single keys.

Comment: @n.m.: Using `setxkbmap` or chaging the layout in KDE? Because changing the layout in KDE doesn't work when I tested it.

Comment: @AndreySidorov: Ok, I see now they're defined in "keysymdef.h", was just hoping it corresponds to some known encoding..

Comment: Hm, with the KDE switcher it doesn't work for me either.

Comment: ...but the KDE switcher doesn't actually switch the layout in my configuration! Only changes the country flags. I'm accessing this machine with VNC from Windows. Only the Windows layout switcher works. I will test it on my home machine later (KDE, direct access, no VNC),

Comment: What happens on my home computer is each keycode being mapped to SIX keycaps (I have a trilingual layout, and each language has normal and shifted keys). All six are printed for each KeyPress event. I never get any layout change events, because the layout stays the same. I guess in this situation you need to track the current group and shift state but I don't know how to track them. Gosh, things got complicated since last time I've looked.

Comment: @n.m. how do you select which group to use?

Comment: it is complicated indeed - http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/kbproto/xkbproto.html#Computing_Effective_Modifier_and_Group

Comment: @AndreySidorov I toggle with alt+space or alt+shift (set up with setxkbmap), plus KDE allows to assign hotkeys for each group.

Comment: Indeed the X Keyboard Extension, which overrides much of the standard X handling of keys, has a spec defining an alternative eventing flow for keyboard mapping changes.